# c# create instance of Excel workbook from console application

Tags: c#, excel, console-application

I have a Visual Studio solution that contains two projects (1) a C# console application; and (2) a C# Excel Workbook.

The console application creates some data, which I would then like to pass into the workbook.

To do this I have created a method in the Excel workbook project, which receives data from the console application. However, I cannot create an instance of the Excel book. At the moment I am trying:

Excel.Application excelApplication = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Add("MyBook.xls");

I could hard code the path to the xls file, but I don't really want to do this as I would prefer to wrap everything up into a single .exe

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

So basically what you're asking is how to wrap two files (an exe and an excel file), into a single exe.

There is a simple (and fairly clumsy) way of doing this which revolves around using `Resources` in C#, meaning your program will have to do something similar to the following:

1. Take excel file source out of `Resources`, and write it to a file when the program is run (temporary file)
2. Use the Current Directory + excel temp file name to feed into the `Worksheet.Add` method
3. Once edited, store the temporary file's data back into the `Resources` of your exe.

Another possibility would be, instead of using a temporary file, read a stream of bytes directly into `Worksheets.Add` if this is supported by the API (feel free to tell me if this is so).

EDIT: [Great tutorial on using resources in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx).